# Evaluate a twice differentiable limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Evaluate $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) -2f(x) + f(x-h) } { h^2}$$

if $f$ is a twice differentiable function.

I'm not sure how to understand this problem. If I differentiate the numerator I get $f'(x+h) - 2f'(x) + f'(x-h)$ but that doesn't seem to take me anywhere?

Comment: regroup you get $f'(x+h)-f'(x)-(f'(x)-f'(x-h))$.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210264/second-derivative-formula-derivation/210273#210273).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) -2f(x) + f(x-h) } { h^2}$$
apply L'hopital, differentiate wrt h , u get 
$$\frac{f'(x+h) - f'(x-h) } { 2h}$$
again by L'hopital u get

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f''(x+h) +f''(x-h) } { 2}=f''(x)$$

Comment: Why does $-2f(x)$ disappear when you differentiate?

Comment: we are to differentiate w.r.t h , so 2f(x)  is constant

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Use the Taylor formula:
$$f(x\pm h)=f(x)\pm hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}2f''(x)+o(h^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Rewrite

$$ [f(x+h) -2f(x) + f(x-h)] =[f(x+h)-f(x)] -[f(x)-f(x-h)]$$

Divide each portion by $h$. What does that become ? Do it again to arrive to ...

I am sure that you can take from here.