# If $\exists f''(0)$, show $\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)-2f(0)+f(-h)}{h^2}=f''(0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is differentiable and $\exists f''(0)$.
I want to show
$$\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)-2f(0)+f(-h)}{h^2}=f''(0)$$ not using the L'hospital rule.

I know how to calculate with L'hospital rule, but I cannot see how otherwise.

Comment: As a sidenote, $\exists f''(0)$ is a horrible jargon of notation

Comment: Use [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) theorem

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How can I write it neatly with the result making sense?

Comment: @izimath you just say “and $f’’(x)$ exists.” Typically when you use $\exists$ you are talking about the existence of some variable satisfying an expression. The use of the symbol here doesn’t make sense. Although it may seem like what I suggested and what you wrote are the same thing, it goes against the standard existence notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one proof which is an adaptation of the proof of Taylor's theorem as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2586741/72031).

---

Let $$g(x) =f(x) - \frac{x^2}{2}f''(0)-xf'(0)-f(0)\tag{1}$$ so that $$g(0)=g'(0)=g''(0)=0\tag{2}$$ and then $$g(h) - 2g(0)+g(-h)=f(h)-2f(0)+f(-h)-h^2f''(0)$$ so that our job is done if we show that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(h)-2g(0)+g(-h)}{h^2}=0\tag{3}$$ Let's note that by definition of derivative we have $$g'(x) =g'(0)+xg''(0)+o(x)=o(x)$$ and by mean value theorem we have $$g(h) =g(0)+hg'(\xi)=hg'(\xi) $$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $h$. And using previous equation we can see that $$g(h) =ho(\xi) =o(h^2)$$ as $0<|\xi|<|h|$. And changing sign of $h$ we get $$g(-h) =o(h^2)$$ Using these we can easily see that $(3)$ holds and we are done.

Comment: very neat, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f''(0)$ does exist, $$f(h) = f(0) + h \cdot f'(0) + \frac{h^2 \cdot f''(0)}{2!} + o(h^2)$$

$$f(-h) = f(0) - h \cdot f'(0) + \frac{h^2 \cdot f''(0)}{2!} + o(h^2)$$

Upon adding we get ,

$$f(h)+f(-h)-2f(0) =  h^2 \cdot f''(0)+o(h^2)$$

$$\frac {f(h)+f(-h)-2f(0)}{h^2} = f''(0) + o(h^2)/h^2$$

Let $h\to 0$ and the desired result is achieved.

Comment: Why does the first equation hold? $f$ is only differentiable.

Comment: The OP states that $f''(0)$ does exist.

Comment: As I indicate in my solution, the $h^3$ term also cancels (all odd terms cancel) so it is $O(h^4)$.

Comment: Taylor theorem doesn't give $O(h^3)$ error, just $o(h^2),$ which suffices.

Comment: Interestingly, the [proof for Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Proof_for_Taylor's_theorem_in_one_real_variable) uses L'Hôpital's rule – for which OP wanted an alternative.

Comment: @MartinR I guess Lhospital is inevitable.

Comment: @MartinR: see this proof of Taylor's theorem without L'Hospital's Rule : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809307/72031

Answer (score 0):

Use two Taylor series for $f'$ at $0$ using steps $h$ and $-h$.

$$f(h) = f(0) + h \cdot f'(0) + \frac{h^2 \cdot f''(0)}{2!} + \frac{h^3 \cdot f'''(0)}{3!} + \frac{h^4 \cdot f''''(0)}{4!} ...$$
$$f(-h) = f(0) - h \cdot f'(0) + \frac{h^2 \cdot f''(0)}{2!} - \frac{h^3 \cdot f'''(0)}{3!} + \frac{h^4 \cdot f''''(0)}{4!} ...$$

Next, lets add them together.

$$f(h) + f(-h) = 2f(0) + 2\frac{h^2 \cdot f''(0)}{2!} + 2\frac{h^4 \cdot f''''(0)}{4!} ...$$

Note the odd powers of $h$ cancel. Solve for $f''(0)$:

$$f''(0) = \frac{f(h) - 2 f(0) + f(-h)}{h^2} + 2\frac{h^2 \cdot f''''(0)}{4!} ...$$

What we have so far is the derivation to the numerical approximation to the second derivative use in computational science. But, just take your  limit and the second and all following terms disappear because h is in the numerator.

Comment: but f is not smooth

Comment: $f'$ cancels. As a matter of fact, all $f^{odd}$ cancel. $f''''$ is multiplied by $h^2$ and higher even derivative by higher powers of $h$. So is does not matter if they are not smooth.

Comment: We cannot use Taylor series in here, since $f'''(0)$ need not exist.