# What is the double derivative of:

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice continuously differentiable function with $f(0)=f(1)=f'(0)=0$ what is $f''(0)$?

Comment: If we assume $f(x)=ax^2(x-1)$ , then the answer is $-2a$, so we need more information.

Comment: well, it could also be a trick question from the beginning: in case you mean the first derivative of $f(0)$, then we clearly get $0$, since the derivative of a constant simply vanishes. And therefore you'd get while following this interpretation $f''(0)=0$. One could distinguish if we'd write $f'(x)\rvert_{x=a}$

Answer (score 0):

There's a type for the 2nd derivate:  [Second derivative "formula derivation"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210264/second-derivative-formula-derivation)
Pick: $$f''(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2}$$ Then simplify, using L'Hôspital's rule, for $x=0\ \ \ \ (x=1).$

Answer (score 0):

The question is not well defined.

As an example: if you chose $y=ax^n(x-1)^m$ than for $n,m>2$ we have $y''(0)=0$, but for $n=m=2$ the sign of $y''(0)$ depends on $a$.

Comment: In OP there are no conditions about $y'(1)$. Anyway on that $y'(1)=0$.

Comment: I didn't noticed, sure.